How to convert a double to string, and back, in a culture independent mode?
I need to convert double precision floating point values (Double) to string and back in a format that should be culture independent.
What is the idiomatic way of doing it Kotlin?
BR.

What exactly do you mean with "culture independent"? Like decimal dot vs. comma, or other things? It would be helpful if you could present some examples. (Here's a similar question for currencies I remember, not sure if that helps.)

"culture independent" is approximately equivalent to regional configuration independent. It means, amongst many other things, how numbers are represented in text form for human readability.

Assuming you are using Kotlin/JVM, the toString methods are not Locale-dependent; therefore you can just use number.toString() and string.toDouble(). The result will be the same as the original number, even though some numbers cannot be exactly represented as decimal. This is because the toString() function will create a string that has just enough decimal precision to uniquely identify the value's Double representation.
Example:
val d = 0.1 + 0.2

// toString() gives 0.30000000000000004. This is correct and not Kotlin's fault.
// See https://0.30000000000000004.com for explanation
val s = d.toString()
println(s)

val d2 = s.toDouble()
println(d == d2)  // prints "true"


The code is part of a library that will be used in systems running over JVM, that's good, but must be compatible with Kotlin Multiplatform and Kotlin Native, as it is part of a distributes system. Is this locale-independence behaviour in toString()/toDouble() consistent with this?

@V.Lorz I don't know if this can be guaranteed across all platforms.

I'm also uncertain about that. Thanks a lot @klitos-kyriacou for your time!

@V.Lorz for Kotlin/Native, the doc says "Note that the representation format is unstable and may change in a future release. However, it is guaranteed that the returned string is valid for converting back to Double using String.toDouble, and will result in the same numeric value. The exact bit pattern of a NaN double is not guaranteed to be preserved though." So that leaves JS and WASM which I still don't know about.

Thanks for pointing at this. I think I'll probably need to dig a bit more on this matter, and to incorporate test cases covering this.

To the extent of what I could check and test, the answers provided by Klitos Kyriacou and Uddyan Semwal are both useful and correct, so this is just for sharing another finding.
Regarding the implementations of toString() and toDouble(), I've just learned they are based on specifications given by standards, IEEE 754 and ECMAScript, and provide consistent interoperation for JVM, Kotlin Multiplatform and Kotlin Native. So, to my opinion, this is the way to go.
Using DecimalFormat(...).format(...) and NumberFormat.getInstance(...).parse(...) seems to be more appropriated when it is necessary to use a specific locale or regional configuration, or when it is a requirement to make numbering formats configurable. It could do the job in my use case, but would add an overhead when compared to using the default implementations for toDouble() and toString().

import java.text.DecimalFormat
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols
import java.util.*

fun doubleToString(value: Double): String {
    val format = DecimalFormat("#.####################") // Pattern with precision to your liking
    format.decimalFormatSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US) // Ensure culture independence (e.g., dot as decimal separator)
    return format.format(value)
}

fun stringToDouble(value: String): Double {
    val format = DecimalFormat("#.####################") // Use the same pattern to ensure correct parsing
    format.decimalFormatSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US) // Consistent locale
    return format.parse(value).toDouble()
}

fun main() {
    val doubleValue = 12345.6789
    val stringValue = doubleToString(doubleValue)
    println("Double to String: $stringValue") // 12345.6789

    val parsedValue = stringToDouble(stringValue)
    println("String to Double: $parsedValue") // 12345.6789
}


Thanks @uddyan-semwal. This is approximately same method I use in other languages, like C#. I'll give it a try.
